# Inheritance: getting the attributes of __init__

Tags: python, inheritance

In the following example, is there any way the `a` attribute in `A` can be accessed by the `B` class or `C` inner class?

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def C_test(self):
        for i in range(4):
            c = self.C()

class C:
    print(self.a)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.a)
```

How come I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Desktop/Pygame/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class A:
  File "/Users/home/Desktop/Pygame/test.py", line 10, in A
    class C:
  File "/Users/home/Desktop/Pygame/test.py", line 11, in C
    print(self.a)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is not a special variable name in Python - it's just the name that is typically given to the first argument of a method, which is bound to the object calling that method.

Your `self.a` in class C doesn't appear inside a method definition where self is listed as an argument, so self has no meaning there.

Comment: How can `C` access `a`, then?

Comment: You'd need an instance of A to access it, since every instance of A has a different copy of `a`.  And if you have an instance of A, called foo, for example, you'd just access it with `foo.a`.

Comment: Call A.__init__ at the beginning of B.__init__.  Or use super.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive a class from your own base-class, you have to call the constructor of the base-class with super to inherit the base-classes attributes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(self)
```

After running this you can do this for example:

```
a = A(1)
b = B()
b.a = a.a
```

b has declared no attribute a, but inherits it from class A by calling the constructor of A via super in class B.
Now b.a evaluates 1 cause it is set to the value of a.a.

Answer (score 0):

For your B example, this general idea does work, just not automatically. Python does Python does have broadly similar rules to Java when it comes to single inheritance. The reason it doesn't work automatically here is because of Python's data model - member variables are attached to each unique *instance*, rather than being an intrinsic part of the class. They're usually, as in your examples, attached to the instance when `__init__` runs. So, for your B to have an `a`, it would need to be attached by `A.__init__`. Python will automatically run that for you if you don't write a `B.__init__`, but if you do have that, you need to call up explicitly. The easiest way is this:

```
 class B(A):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
```

Again, you might recognise this idea of explicitly chaining up using super from other languages - although the spelling is a bit different here. But the only major technical difference between Python and Java in this respect is that Python needs the parent constructor to be called for the instance variables to even *exist* (in Java, they will still exist, but might not have the right value, or even be initialised).

For your C example, Python is *very* different from Java here. Python doesn't usually use the term 'inner class', although you *can* define a class inside another class (note that you haven't in your code sample, though) - but instances of the inner class won't be associated with an instance of the outer class. So, they behave a bit more like Java inner *static* classes. You could associate them explicitly by doing something like this:

```
 class A:
     def __init__(self, a):
         self.a = a
         self.my_C = A.C(self)

     class C:
           def __init__(self, A_self):
               print(A_self.a)
```

But this isn't exactly common, and depending on exactly what your problem is, there is almost always a better way to solve it than trying to shoehorn Java idioms into Python code.